# MySQL, C++: Need Blob size to read blob data

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2008, blob

**How do I get the size of data in a BLOB field in the Result Set?** *(Using C++ and MySQL Connector C++)*

In order to read the data from the result set, I have allocate memory for it first.  In order to allocate memory, I need to know the size of the blob data in the result set.

Searching the web and StackOverflow, I have found two methods:  `OCTECT` and BLOB stream.

One method to find the BLOB size is to use `OCTECT()` function, which requires a new query and produces a new result set.  I would rather not use this method.

Another method is to use the blob stream and seek to the end, and get the file position.  However, I don't know if the stream can be rewound to the beginning in order to read the data.  This method requires an additional read of the entire stream.

The `ResultSet` and `ResultSetMetaData` interfaces of *MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5* do not provide a method for obtaining the size of the data in a field (column).

Is there a process for obtaining the size of the data in a BLOB field given only the result set and a field name?

I am using MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5, C++, Visual Studio 2008, Windows Vista / XP and "Server version: 5.1.41-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a select like:

```
select LENGTH(content),content where id=123;
```

where content is the BLOB field.

Regards.
see: [LENGTH(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

Comment: What is the field name, in the result set, for the LENGTH() field?

Comment: It should be possible to access the result with the index (here 1).
In java I will call 'rs.setInt(1)'.

Comment: The field name for the length() is as written: `length(content)`. To get a sensible name you have to do `length(content) as contentLength` or similar.